# Is it possible to know if a real mouse is used on a device with touch features using javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, touch, mouse, modernizr

I'am working on a web site and I'am using modernizer to know if a device is touch compatible.
In this case, i filter all 'hover' of html tags of my application.
example : .no-touch div.cell:hover

But how can I know if the user also uses a real mouse on a touch device ?
More and more devices allow both and i want to display 'hover' on touch devices when a user prefers to use a mouse instead of (touch).

I'am using angularjs then a related solution should be great.

Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't using a real mouse be somewhat counter productive? How would one connect a real mouse to a computer, by sticking a cable up it's ass, and what if the little bugger bites you, they have sharp teeth and can carry disease you know? Seems more practical to use a computer mouse!

Comment: Here you can find a discussion about it https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/issues/869 and an article http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/touchandmouse/  there's a move about it but i don't know if there's a general solution

Comment: Lol adeneo !   
Thanks keypaul, I had already found this pages but there are some discussion but not a real solution...

Answer (score 0):

Mouse events should trigger `click` events, whereas Touch events should trigger the `touch` events.  However, let it be known now that some touch screens (typically older models) don't have "real" touch capability.  All they do is take the touch input and convert it into clicks.

Also, I don't think the :hover attribute ever cares if it's mouse or touch.  I think the only calculation that goes into that is whether or not the cursor is above the given element.